# Oracle splitting date range into day and custom time intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to split work shift date range into different date and time interval.  Already found some answers, but still trying to split by time interval. Thanks in advance for any ideas or tips.

1. Each day need to be split out separately
2. Day Shift is 0600-22:00
3. Night Shift is 2200-0600

```
Range1:
2022-02-03 08:40 to 2022-02-04 10:07
Split Rows:
   2022-02-03 08:40 to 2022-02-03 22:00 DAY
   2022-02-03 22:00 to 2022-02-04 06:00 NIGHT
   2022-02-04 06:00 to 2022-02-04 10:07 DAY
Range2:
2022-02-03 08:40 to 2022-02-04 02:07
Split Rows:
   2022-02-03 08:40 to 2022-02-03 22:00 DAY
   2022-02-03 22:00 to 2022-02-04 02:07 NIGHT
Range3:
2022-02-03 04:40 to 2022-02-04 02:07
Split Rows:
   2022-02-03 04:40 to 2022-02-03 06:00 NIGHT
   2022-02-03 08:40 to 2022-02-03 22:00 DAY
   2022-02-03 22:00 to 2022-02-04 02:07 NIGHT
```

Sample data (Using lateral query is not working yet. I will update, if i figure it out) Also trying to see whether i can split them per hour and sum up later as in here [splitting time into hour intervals](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4477700/split-date-range-rows-into-day-intervals)

```
WITH SAMPLE AS (
   SELECT
      1  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 10:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      2  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      3  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 04:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
)
SELECT
   ID,
   L.STARTDATE,
   L.ENDDATE
FROM
   SAMPLE,
   LATERAL (
      SELECT
         CASE LEVEL
            WHEN 1 THEN STARTDATE
            ELSE TRUNC(STARTDATE) + LEVEL - 1
         END                                                         STARTDATE,
         LEAST(TRUNC(STARTDATE) + LEVEL - 1 / 24 / 60, ENDDATE) ENDDATE
      FROM
         DUAL
      CONNECT BY
         TRUNC(STARTDATE) + LEVEL - 1 <= ENDDATE
   ) L;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
WITH SAMPLE (ID, startdate, enddate ) AS (
   SELECT 1, 
          TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
          TO_DATE('2022-02-04 10:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
   FROM   DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 
          TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
          TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
   FROM   DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 
          TO_DATE('2022-02-03 04:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
          TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
   FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT ID,
       o.type,
       GREATEST(L.start_date + o.start_offset, s.startdate) AS startdate,
       LEAST(L.start_date + o.end_offset, s.enddate) AS enddate
FROM   SAMPLE s
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT TRUNC(startdate - INTERVAL '6' HOUR)
                  + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
                  + LEVEL - 1 AS start_date
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY
                TRUNC(startdate - INTERVAL '6' HOUR)
                  + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
                  + LEVEL - 1
                < ENDDATE
       ) L
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT 'DAY' AS type,
                INTERVAL '0' HOUR AS start_offset,
                INTERVAL '16' HOUR AS end_offset
         FROM   DUAL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT 'NIGHT' AS type,
                INTERVAL '16' HOUR AS start_offset,
                INTERVAL '24' HOUR AS end_offset
         FROM   DUAL
       ) o
WHERE  L.start_date + o.start_offset < s.enddate
AND    L.start_date + o.end_offset > s.startdate;
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | TYPE | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | DAY | 2022-02-03 08:40:00 | 2022-02-03 22:00:00 |
> | 1 | NIGHT | 2022-02-03 22:00:00 | 2022-02-04 06:00:00 |
> | 1 | DAY | 2022-02-04 06:00:00 | 2022-02-04 10:07:00 |
> | 2 | DAY | 2022-02-03 08:40:00 | 2022-02-03 22:00:00 |
> | 2 | NIGHT | 2022-02-03 22:00:00 | 2022-02-04 02:07:00 |
> | 3 | NIGHT | 2022-02-03 04:40:00 | 2022-02-03 06:00:00 |
> | 3 | DAY | 2022-02-03 06:00:00 | 2022-02-03 22:00:00 |
> | 3 | NIGHT | 2022-02-03 22:00:00 | 2022-02-04 02:07:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d8c7d9bd946b8e46a2fe4aaa3737b347)*

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.**

First of all you need to generate all possible intervals. You can do it using simple lateral. To make it easier and more agile, I'll save day shifts in the `INTERVALS` CTE:

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f32198aef2158b6ed9246d5f635baac7)

```sql
WITH SAMPLE AS (
   SELECT
      1  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 10:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      2  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      3  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 04:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
)
,intervals(i_name,i_start,i_end) as (
select 'Day Shift'  ,'0600', '2159' from dual union all
select 'Night Shift','2200', '0559' from dual
)
SELECT
   s.*
   ,days.*
   ,ints.*
FROM
   SAMPLE s
  ,lateral(
      select trunc(startdate) + n as n_day
      from xmltable(
         '-1 to xs:integer(.)'
         passing trunc(trunc(enddate) - trunc(startdate))
         columns n int path '.'
      ) 
   ) days
  ,lateral(
      select 
         i.*
        ,to_date(to_char(n_day,'yyyy-mm-dd ')||i_start, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24mi')
           as dtm_start
        ,to_date(to_char(n_day,'yyyy-mm-dd ')||i_end  , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24mi')
         + case when i_end < i_start then 1 else 0 end -- +1 if it ends on next day
           as dtm_end
      from intervals i
   ) ints
order by id,startdate,n_day,dtm_start;
```

Results:

```
 ID STARTDATE           ENDDATE             N_DAY      I_NAME      I_ST I_EN DTM_START           DTM_END
--- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------- ---- ---- ------------------- -------------------
  1 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 10:07:00 2022-02-02 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-02 06:00:00 2022-02-02 21:59:00
  1 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 10:07:00 2022-02-02 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-02 22:00:00 2022-02-03 05:59:00
  1 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 10:07:00 2022-02-03 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-03 06:00:00 2022-02-03 21:59:00
  1 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 10:07:00 2022-02-03 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-03 22:00:00 2022-02-04 05:59:00
  1 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 10:07:00 2022-02-04 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-04 06:00:00 2022-02-04 21:59:00
  1 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 10:07:00 2022-02-04 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-04 22:00:00 2022-02-05 05:59:00
  2 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-02 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-02 06:00:00 2022-02-02 21:59:00
  2 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-02 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-02 22:00:00 2022-02-03 05:59:00
  2 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-03 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-03 06:00:00 2022-02-03 21:59:00
  2 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-03 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-03 22:00:00 2022-02-04 05:59:00
  2 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-04 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-04 06:00:00 2022-02-04 21:59:00
  2 2022-02-03 08:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-04 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-04 22:00:00 2022-02-05 05:59:00
  3 2022-02-03 04:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-02 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-02 06:00:00 2022-02-02 21:59:00
  3 2022-02-03 04:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-02 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-02 22:00:00 2022-02-03 05:59:00
  3 2022-02-03 04:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-03 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-03 06:00:00 2022-02-03 21:59:00
  3 2022-02-03 04:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-03 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-03 22:00:00 2022-02-04 05:59:00
  3 2022-02-03 04:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-04 Day Shift   0600 2159 2022-02-04 06:00:00 2022-02-04 21:59:00
  3 2022-02-03 04:40:00 2022-02-04 02:07:00 2022-02-04 Night Shift 2200 0559 2022-02-04 22:00:00 2022-02-05 05:59:00
```

*Note, that since I have specified time intervals in `hhmi` (ie `hh24mi` in oracle datetime format models), we need to ignore seconds.*

As you can see `lateral(...) days` generates all dates between one day before `startdate` (to cover the end of night shift) and `enddate`.

Then `ints` generates day and night shifts for all those days.

**Step 2.**

So the only thing you need now is to filter them and correct start time and end time of partial intervals.

These 2 predicates filters them:

```sql
   and ints.dtm_end   >= s.startdate
   and ints.dtm_start <= s.enddate
```

and these 2 lines return correct start and end time:

```
   greatest(s.startdate, ints.dtm_start) as startdate,
   least   (s.enddate  , ints.dtm_end  ) as enddate,
```

So full solution: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b514628d3d0370892e39c798ea61eb09)

```sql
WITH SAMPLE AS (
   SELECT
      1  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 10:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      2  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 08:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      3  AS ID, 
      TO_DATE('2022-02-03 04:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS STARTDATE,
      TO_DATE('2022-02-04 02:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS ENDDATE
   FROM
      DUAL
)
,intervals(i_name,i_start,i_end) as (
select 'Day Shift'  ,'0600', '2159' from dual union all
select 'Night Shift','2200', '0559' from dual
)
SELECT
   s.id,
   greatest(s.startdate, ints.dtm_start) as startdate,
   least   (s.enddate  , ints.dtm_end  ) as enddate,
   i_name,
   i_start,
   i_end
FROM
   SAMPLE s
  ,lateral(
      select trunc(startdate) + n as n_day
      from xmltable(
         '-1 to xs:integer(.)'
         passing trunc(trunc(enddate) - trunc(startdate))
         columns n int path '.'
      ) 
   ) days
  ,lateral(
      select 
         i.*
        ,to_date(to_char(n_day,'yyyy-mm-dd ')||i_start, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24mi')
           as dtm_start
        ,to_date(to_char(n_day,'yyyy-mm-dd ')||i_end  , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24mi')
         + case when i_end < i_start then 1 else 0 end -- +1 if it ends on next day
           as dtm_end
      from intervals i
   ) ints
where 1=1
   -- filter `ints`:
   and ints.dtm_end   >= s.startdate
   and ints.dtm_start <= s.enddate
order by 1,2,3;
```

Results:

```
        ID STARTDATE        ENDDATE          I_NAME      I_ST I_EN
---------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------- ---- ----
         1 2022-02-03 08:40 2022-02-03 21:59 Day Shift   0600 2159
         1 2022-02-03 22:00 2022-02-04 05:59 Night Shift 2200 0559
         1 2022-02-04 06:00 2022-02-04 10:07 Day Shift   0600 2159
         2 2022-02-03 08:40 2022-02-03 21:59 Day Shift   0600 2159
         2 2022-02-03 22:00 2022-02-04 02:07 Night Shift 2200 0559
         3 2022-02-03 04:40 2022-02-03 05:59 Night Shift 2200 0559
         3 2022-02-03 06:00 2022-02-03 21:59 Day Shift   0600 2159
         3 2022-02-03 22:00 2022-02-04 02:07 Night Shift 2200 0559

8 rows selected.
```

Obviously, you can remove `i_start` and `i_end` columns from the output. I showed them just to highlight day/night shift intervals.

Comment: Time ranges are typically inclusive for the start and exclusive for the end. That way you don't need hacks such deducing one minute from the end time. *(Or should it be 1s? Or 0.001s? With exclusive end times, it's unambiguous.)*

Comment: @MatBailie yeah, you are right, you can simply change intervals definition and predicate `<=` to `<` - there is nothing difficult. But I do not agree re "typically" - It depends on many nuances including data types and business area. Oracle `date` type precision is just up to seconds, it has no fractional part of seconds. While `timestamp` precision can be up to timestamp(9) - nanosecond and yes - we really often use exclusive predicates with them. But not always, just for example - when we need accurate intervals, not with end time *1s? Or 0.001s?* in future

Comment: This solution also works. Thanks for explaining how code works as well, I haven't used lateral before.